# How to get coordinates from the PostgreSQL point object

Tags: postgresql

I have a point column in my PostgreSQL table. Is there a way to extract point's X/Y coordinates separately? I operate with native PostgreSQL data, not PostGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html) tells you:

> It is possible to access the two component numbers of a `point` as though the point were an array with indexes 0 and 1. For example, if `t.p` is a `point` column then `SELECT p[0] FROM t` retrieves the X coordinate and `UPDATE t SET p[1] = ...` changes the Y coordinate.

Comment: Somehow this works:

`select pt[1] from (select point(1, 2) as pt) as x`

and this does not: 

`select point(1, 2)[1] as x`

Comment: And why on earth does indexing start from 0 here, while array indexing starts from 1????

Comment: For the first example, you are missing a pair of parentheses: `(point(1,2))[1]`. As to "why", such questions are hard to answer. First array indexing does not have to start at 1, it can start anywhere. Then, both features were implemented at different times by different users. And just because both use brackets, that does not mean that they are related.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.